# Status of a conjecture of C.T.C. Wall?

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, 4-manifolds

In Wall's paper [Unknotting tori in codimension one and spheres in codimension two](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/wallunknot.pdf), he states the following conjecture:

> Any $h$-cobordism of $S^3 \times S^1$ to itself is diffeomorphic to $S^3 \times S^1 \times I$.

What is the status of this conjecture?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The conjecture has been solved. This is Theorem 16.1 in *C.T.C. Wall. (1999). Surgery on Compact Manifolds, Second edition. Mathematical Surveys and Monographs,
Vol. 69*. Here, two proofs of this theorem are given: the first one is an application of a more general method presented in the book, while the second one relies on some geometrical properties of $S^3 \times S^1$.