# Unknotted $S^{n-2}$ in $S^n$

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, 4-manifolds

I wonder is it still an open question that   a smooth sphere $\Sigma^{2}\subset S^4$ is unknotted in $S^4$ iff its complement is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$? If it is an open question, how is it related to other known conjectures in 4D?

I know for all the other $n$ this has been settled by Levine 1965 "Unknotting spheres in codimension 2" and Wall 1965 "Unknotting tori in codimension one and spheres in codimension two", see relatedly [Status of a conjecture of C.T.C. Wall?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368325/status-of-a-conjecture-of-c-t-c-wall).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My understanding is this remains an open problem in the smooth category.

I believe there have been a few claims of proofs of this statement in the literature over the years, but as far as I know none of these arguments have been robust.   As I believe you are aware, in the topological category this was done by Mike Freedman.

If you jazz up the conjecture a little you could turn it into a recognition principle for $S^1 \times D^3$, and that could in turn be turned into a proof of the smooth 4-dimensional Poincare conjecture.  Specifically, say you have a homotopy 4-sphere.  Remove a small unknotted $S^2$ (i.e. in some embedded $D^4$ in your homotopy 4-sphere), then its exterior presumably would satisfy the recognition principle for $S^1 \times D^3$.  From this you could argue the homotopy $4$-sphere is the standard smooth $S^4$ by filling in $D^2 \times S^2$.

Comment: No, I was not aware about the topological case resolved by Freedman. Which paper is it? As far as I understand there are 2 versions of the 4D Poincare conjecture: "small" and "large" depending on whether $\Sigma^4\setminus D^4$ embeds or does not embed in $R^4$. The small version is the Schoenflies problem. One would get a recognition principle for a small $S^1\times D^3$, thus the proof of the Shoenflis conjecture?

Comment: I believe it first appears in his 1983 paper "The disk theorem for four-dimensional manifolds" Proc. ICM.  But it's also in the Freedman-Quinn book.

Comment: There are two notions of *unknotted* that one can consider. The first is that there is a diffeomorphism from $S^4$ to $S^4$ taking an embedded $2$-sphere $K$ onto the standard $S^2$. This is what Ryan addresses. The second is that $K$ is isotopic to $S^2$. This is also true, and follows by Quinn/Perron's 1986 result that pseudoisotopy implies topological isotopy. Both versions are still open in the smooth case.

Comment: @DannyRuberman: I think one can show that these two notions are equivalent, provided you demand the diffeomorphism of $S^4$ is orientation-preserving.  One direction is that smooth isotopy implies the diffeomorphism by isotopy extension.  The reverse argument uses the proof of the Cerf decomposition $Diff(S^n) \simeq O_{n+1} \times Diff(D^n)$. The idea is if you have an orientation preserving diffeomorphism of $S^n$ sending one knot to the other, you can linearize that diffeomorphism on any hemi-sphere you like.  The linear part is an element of $SO_{n+1}$ which is connected. . .

Comment: So if you do a preliminary shrinking of the knot to lie in a hemi-sphere, the linearization process together with the path to the identity in $_{+1}$ gives you the isotopy of one knot to the other. i.e. for any proper submanifold $M$ of $^$, the restriction fibration $(^n)\to (,^n)$ factors (up to homotopy) through $_{n+1} \to (,^n)$, the exotic diffeomorphisms of discs are a null family for this map.